# Uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, error-messages, ajax-toolkit

So I've been running into an odd problem. I am attempting to add a button to a custom visual force page that will change ownership without going to an edit page. For some reason it's throwing an error.

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/30.0/integration.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function takeOwnershipOfSR(){
        var myCustomObj = new sforce.SObject("My_Custom_Object__c");
            myCustomObj.id = '{!My_Custom_Object__c.Id}';
            myCustomObj.OwnerId = '{!$User.Id}';

        var result = sforce.connection.update([myCustomObj]);

        if (result[0].success == 'false') {
            alert('Ownership not changed. Reason: ' + result[0].errors.message);
        }
        else {
            location.reload(true); /* redisplay the detail page */
        }
    }
</script>
```

The error says

> Uncaught TypeError: sforce.SObject is not a constructor.

The internets are not blessing me with any answers and I've confirmed `SObject` has the proper capital letters. The code also works on other pages but not this one for some reason. Thoughts?

Comment: just a check, have you included connection.js and apex.js ?

Comment: I think that's done in the integration.js

Comment: that's definitely library

Comment: @IlyaLepesh My first guess too. Except the other page has the same library and it works

Comment: If you open the console, do you get any loading errors?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I was but errors not related. Things such couldn't load some logos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is supplied by `connection.js` ([AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_connecting.htm)), not `integration.js` ([Console Integration Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_connecting.htm)).

The following will not throw any error.

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function takeOwnershipOfSR(){
        var myCustomObj = new sforce.SObject("Nonexistent_SObject__c");
    }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Likely, on the pages where your above functionality works, it is because `connection.js` is already included elsewhere on the page.**

Comment: I promise connection.js isn't included anywhere on the page (template-less and componentless). My follow up question would be if connection.js and Integration.js can be included on the same page without major conflicts. (Personal so I'll accept your answer)

Comment: Right, that question has a very different scope. I'm a bit perplexed why the above would work without `connection.js`. What about `apex.js`, is that present perchance?

Comment: So out of curiosity I went and checked through, integration is the only javascript library included. I even checked the controller to make sure no goofy stuff was going on with merge fields (or whatever they're called on VF pages) and there's nothing. It bothers me though and was one of the big reason I was so stubborn that my libraries were right.,

Comment: Yeah, I'm at a loss for why it *ever* worked. It shouldn't have. Maybe there is some sort of dependency loading that goes on. Could be dependent on API Version too, but I can only offer conjecture since I couldn't reproduce. If you have developer support, you should open a case to discover why it *does* work and report back. :)

Comment: I think my company has some of that but it's one of those things where I'm afraid to ask because if they realize it does work they might "fix" it into not working.

Comment: Well, you know the expected behavior now so it's easy to fix. :) But I get it. Can't say I blame you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with is this line:

```
var myCustomObj = new sforce.SObject("My_Custom_Object__c");
```

It should read something like:

```
var myCustomObj = new My_Custom_Object__c;
```

sforce is only used in lightning, not in visualforce. If you're trying to call an Action, you can use the `$Action` and `URLFor` as in:

```
<apex:outputLink value = URLFOR("$Action.new.My_Custom_Object__c")>;
```

to take you to the detail page to create the new record which doesn't appear to be what you want to do. That's just extra info.

Comment: Sadly the same error occurs and this doesn't explain why it works on the other pages that have it without the $ObjectType

Comment: You are using this page for lightning, correct?

Comment: Nope. Just a normal VF page

Comment: sforce.one isn't for use with normal VF pages. I'll edit the code to show you what you need.

Comment: Why does it work on some pages but not others?

Comment: Can't say why it works on some except to say that SF is working on the platform to enable sforce commands in Visualforce for where they're ultimately headed with the Lightning Experience on the platform. That's the only reason I can think of. It could also be because you're using JS to create an object that SF recognizes in most cases.

Comment: I think this is off base...`sforce` is not designed to be specific to lightning. The `AJAX` toolkit is much more ubiquitous than that. Something else is at play here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson In Visualforce it most definitely is Lightning specific. Just look at the documentation. In JS, I can't say how well it's supported when used in contexts outside of Lightning. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm.

Comment: No. `sforce.one` is lightning specific. `sforce.connection` is not. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples_asynch.htm

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you for the clarification. In the context of Ajax and JS, what you say makes perfect sense. I think I said something similar might be the case someplace above. Thank you for the reference.